associations, specializations and multiplicity in class diagram
in this class diagram I would like to represent the following specifications.

an instance of spec1 can be associated with an instance of class2 for different years.
an instance of spec1 can be associated in the same year to multiple instances of class2.
an instance of spec2 can be associated with multiple instances of class2 in the same year.
at this point I thought of inserting a discriminant attribute in class1 to indicate whether a spec can have one or more associations per year

I drew these two class diagrams, are they good as a representation of the problem?


for the frequency of associations could I insert a discriminating attribute such as a boolean attribute or an enumeration to indicate if spec1 can have multiple associations in the same year?
If so, what changes when using one or the other?
how would it change in the two class diagrams?

a spec1 can be associated with class2 once a year to a single instance of class2 or several times in the same year to the same class2 or different instances of class2 Doesn't make much sense to me. I don't understand what you are trying to say. An object (instance) cannot be associated to a class. Only to other objects (instances)

I would like to represent the following specifications. 1) an instance of spec1 can be associated with an instance of class2 for different years. 2) an instance of spec1 can be associated in the same year to multiple instances of class2. 3) an instance of spec2 can be associated with multiple instances of class2 in the same year. at this point I thought of inserting a discriminant attribute in class1 to indicate whether a spec can have one or more associations per year.

there can be instances of spec1 that can be associated with a class2 every year or instances that can be associated with multiple instances of class2 even in the same year

Please don't add clarifications in comments. Instead edit your question to make it more clear.

On a quick look the top one is more concise. You could adorn it with constraints to express the additional requirements.
